# Is it possible to do frame by frame animation without AnimationDrawable?

Tags: android, animation

I'm using a lot of animation drawables on my app and not all frames are gettings played. I'm wondering if there is another, more efficient method of doing frame by frame animations than AnimationDrawable?

Comment: No, I've been supplied frames to build the animations. It's part of a whack-a-mole type game where there are 20 different types of moles popping out of boxes that also need animating. The moles have 3 different types of animations each (up, down, down shaking).

Answer (score 0):

Try [this Android tutorial](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-paint-animate-loop-and-remove-a-sprite/) about SurfaceViews. You can implement them in you XML layout + you can easily manipulate each frame.